# How to create eventbridge rule using boto3 with lambda function as target?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-event-bridge

I wanted to create an AWS eventbridge rule with lambda function as the target. The lambda function named '**StartInstance**' has been already created via console.

I have created a python script which is using boto3 library to create this eventbridge rule. I am passing a cron expression to this rule which would invoke the lambda function at a particular date and time.

Here is the code of python script which runs successfully:

```
import boto3

eventclient = boto3.client('events')

response = eventclient.put_rule(
    Name='ec2scheduler',
    ScheduleExpression='cron(40 16 21 4 ? 2021)',
    State='ENABLED',
    Description='schedule ec2 start/stop'
)

response = eventclient.put_targets(
    Rule='ec2scheduler',
    Targets=[
        {
            'Id': 'StartInstance',
            'Arn': 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:965477548122:function:StartInstance'
        }
    ]
)
```

As you can see, cron expression passed to the rule is: `cron(40 16 21 4 ? 2021)` Which should have invoked the 'StartInstance' lambda function on Date 21-April-2021 at 16:40 hrs GMT. However, the lambda function didn't get invoked at that time. I see no logs generated for lambda function in cloudwatch logs as well. The eventbridge rule created above looks fine to me when I see it via AWS Eventbridge console with the required target and cron expression visible in console. But the rule doesn't invoke the lambda function when time comes.

Why is this happening?

Comment: are you schdeuling lambda via console?did you you give permissions to lambda in the form of role? have you created rule in event bridge which has corn expression which tells when to invoke lambda and target of the rule as your lambda function?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: Permissions/Trust needs to be established on lambda and eventbridge

**Explanation**

Couple of things missing here:

First:

When you add a rule and a target from the console, AWS does the job of creating a lambda event source mapping. In this case, the EventBridge rule should be configured as the event source for the lambda function.

The [create_event_source_mapping](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_event_source_mapping) lambda API will let you add this mapping explicitly. This has to be done in the code after you create the target and the rule.

Second:

In the parameters for the [put_rule](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#EventBridge.Client.put_rule) EventBridge API, I don't see the RoleArn mentioned. The ARN for the role which the rule will use needs to have the permission to invoke the target lambda function.

Comment: I don't think you need to pass a role to the rule or the rule target, as long as you create a policy statement between your rule as the principal/source and the lambda function. See the call to `lambda_client.add_permission` in [this example](https://dev.to/maverik/use-boto3-create-eventbridge-rule-tigger-lambda-function-blj).

Answer (score 0):

Attach the policy AmazonEventBridgeFullAccess to the role.